# Starting new Activity with different Orientation affect to first one

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation

I"m starting activity how is defined inside the manifest :

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.X.video.videoplayerapp.VideoIMA32"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

from activity that defined  :

```
        android:name="com.X.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeBar" />
```

It makes the main activity to change to landscape for a seconds when you getting back to it .

Why the new activity affect on the the old one ? i"m guessing its related to the manifest some how ...

UPDATE : happen only on pixel , maybe this is a happening only on some devices but for sure on all devices something not good happening to the old activity when you go back from the new activity from different orientation

Thanks .

Comment: Hi, 
Any fix on this?

Comment: No ...Was not manage to fix that .